# Changing Windows SDK Between Builds in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015

I have a project that will target two different builds: one that supports only Direct3D 11, and another that supports both Direct3D 11 and Direct3D 12.  I am doing this so that the project can run on earlier versions of Windows by eliminating the link to the Direct3D 12 library.

When I go to the project settings page, I change the target platform version from 8.1 to 10.0.1.10240.0 in order to let the compiler search the correct directories.  Doing this causes that property to be changed across all builds, not just the currently selected build, making it impossible to do what I'm trying to do.

Is this a bug, a feature, or am I just not doing it right?  Do I really need to set the target platform version between builds to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Well, sure, that's the way it works.  You'll probably discover why it works that way when you do this the right way, changing the VC++ Directories settings for each configuration.  Pretty painful, isn't it?

Comment: @HansPassant Do I need to do that though?  The 10 SDK should run on 7 and 8 as long as I only include libraries that exist on 7 and 8, right?